# "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol') " React axios

Tags: reactjs

Getting that error in console when trying to get data from a API. Anybody have this issue before?

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import "../App.css"
import axios from "axios"
const Main = () => {
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [data,setData] = useState ([])
    useEffect (() =>{
        setLoading(true)
        axios({
            method:"GET",
            URL:'https://fakestoreapi.com/products',
         
        }).then(res => {
            console.log (res.data)
            setData(res.data)
        })
        .finally(()=> setLoading(false))
    },[])
  return (
   <div></div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

the error I am getting is :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')
    at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js:57:1)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:147:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:16:1)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:58:1)
    at Axios.request (Axios.js:109:1)
    at wrap (bind.js:9:1)
    at Main.js:10:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
```

anyone have an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change URL to url

```
 axios({
        method:"GET",
        url:'https://fakestoreapi.com/products',
})
```

And if the above code doesn't work try to send a GET request like this,

```
axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products').then().catch().finally()
```